# Python TypeError: 'fp' is not a file-like object or it does not take bytes: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, json, vk, gtts

the essence of the code is that it converts my messages into voice messages by deleting, converting, saving, downloading and sending. Made 4 functions.
1 is responsible for saving, 2 for uploading to the server, 3 for catching the message, 4 for sending. TypeError: 'fp' is not a file-like object or it does not take bytes: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

```
import requests
import random, vk_api, vk
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import sys
import time
import threading
import json
import gtts
import datetime
import queue
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

dt = datetime.datetime.today()

namegs=(random.randrange(0,1000,1))

print(namegs)

q = queue.Queue()

atchdoc=("null")

token = "TOKEN"
message_text = ("null")
file_path = ('null')

print("Попыта авторизации...")
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session, wait=10)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
print("Авторизация прошла успешно!")

def SaveGS():
file_path = ("null")
messagegs=gtts.gTTS(q.get(), lang="ru")
messagegs.save("abc.ogg")
file_path = ("abc.ogg")
q.put(file_path)
print (file_path)
print('начинаем загружать запись..')
time.sleep(1)
LoadGS()


def LoadGS():
file_path = ("null")
url = "URL"; 
url = url.replace("\/","/"); 
file_path = q.get(file_path)
response = requests.post(url, files={"file": open(file_path, 'rb')});
resp1=(response.content)
resp1 = resp1[9:]
resp1 = str(resp1, 'utf-8')
resp1 = resp1.replace('}', '')
resp1 = resp1.replace('"', '')
url2 = "https://api.vk.com/method/docs.save?file=" + resp1 + "&access_token=" + token + "&v=5.81"
response1 = requests.post(url2, files={"file": open(file_path, "rb")})
resp2 = (response1.text)
resp2 = resp2[19:-934]
docid = resp2
atchdoc = "doc378218712_" + docid
q.put(atchdoc)
print("DocumentID" + atchdoc)
print("сообщение загружено..")
time.sleep(5)
MessageIMPORT()

print("Подходим к нужному методу!")

def MessageEXPORT():
for event in longpoll.listen():

print("Attachment ID : "+ atchdoc)

print("лонгпул работает")
if atchdoc != "null":
LoadGS()
else:
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.text:
dictmessID = vk.messages.getHistory(
count=1,
user_id=event.user_id
)
evvchtid=event.user_id
q.put(evvchtid)
message_id = dictmessID["items"]
message_text = event.text
print(message_text)
message_id = '; '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}:{x[1]}', dictmessID.items()))
message_id = message_id.split(',')[2]
message_id = message_id.split(':')[1]
message_id = message_id.replace(" ", "")
print("Message_ID: " + message_id)
q.put(message_text)
vk.messages.delete(
message_ids=message_id,
delete_for_all=True
)
print('сообщение удалено..')

SaveGS()





def MessageIMPORT():
print("отправляем сообщение!")
vk.messages.send(
message=(),
user_id=q.get(evvchtid),
random_id=get_random_id(),
attachment=q.get(atchdoc))
print("Голосовое сообщение отправлено!")
MessageEXPORT()







MessageEXPORT()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'fp' is not a file-like object or it does not take bytes: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

An error came out, I don’t understand at all what the essence is, I tried some correction methods (I didn’t delete pieces of this code) I hope you can help .. ((

Comment: The message was cut off, I forgot to say hello. sorry

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Correct indentation is critical for understanding Python.

Comment: I don't see a variable `fp` anywhere in the code. You need to post the full traceback.

Comment: The error is very likely  raised by the write_to_fp function of the gtts module (check https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html). This function is itself called by the save function. So I would presume that the problem is coming from messagegs.save. A full traceback would be certainly useful, but meanwhile try changing the file name / extension, or check the content of the messagegs variable

Comment: Just for helping, I am going to have a guess on the traceback : problems comes from text.strip in self._tokenise in self._prepare_requests in self.steam in self.write_to_fp in messagegs.save. Check the text attribute of your messagegs variable , it is probably an int

Comment: And the text attributes seems to be the returned value of q.get()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by copying and pasting, starting at the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like code. Please also read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to determine and show only the part of the code needed to cause the problem (make sure the error message corresponds to that code).

Comment: "The message was cut off, I forgot to say hello. sorry" not a problem; [it is better not to say those things here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950).

Comment: Guys, many thanks to all those who answered my mistake, as soon as I can I will try to solve it with your metas and send a full traceback!!

Comment: Karl Knechtel, I understand, sorry